# Look outside of the viewport with Chrome developer tools

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, viewport, developer-tools

Is there any way for me to see content outside of the browser's normal viewport with the chrome developer tools? I'm moving an item outside of the browser's view, but I want to see exactly how far it's moving.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is super helpful or not, but when I've had to do this for, say, "hiding" an element that still must display in order to get around IE6/7's form security, I would zoom the browser window out. This would let me see where the element I moved ended up, relative to the main content of the page.

Comment: Couldn't you just shift everything to one side, so what would normally be the edge is in the center? Then just leave your object where you like and move everything back to original position. I put borders on all my divs when I'm trying to see where everything is in relation to each other.

Answer (score 14):

I know this answer comes too late but just in case anyone wondering - in `Chrome Developer Tools` -> ⋮ -> `More tools` -> `Layers`.

Comment: It's never too late :) thank you for pointing this useful tool.